# Visualizar estado checkbox con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

estoy intentando conocer desde javascript el valor de una checkbox (true,false), estoy usando este código en html:

```
<div class="switch-button">
     <input type="checkbox" name="bCaldera" id="switch-label" class="switch-button__checkbox">
     <label for="switch-label" class="switch-button__label"></label>
```

Y este es el código de mi javascript y el fallo que me da la consola de google:
[image: fallo en consola]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código de JS en texto en lugar de usar screenshots. Haz el recorrido (que está en el footer) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

El error parece provenir de que estás revisando el atributo `checked` directamente sin que este asociado a ningún evento, por lo que de base será `false` al no estar seleccionado.

En el `if` que tienes escrito evaluará si es `true` y dado que no lo es de base y no se registra el cambio, no hará nada ya que no hay ningún bloque `else`.

Pruebalo de esta manera para ver si sigue dando error:

```js
const switchLabel = document.getElementById('switch-label');

function switchChange () {
  console.log(switchLabel.checked)
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-button">
     <input type="checkbox" name="bCaldera" id="switch-label" class="switch-button__checkbox" onchange="switchChange()">
     <label for="switch-label" class="switch-button__label"></label>
```

Comment: no termino de  entender que hace, no veo nada en la consola.

Comment: prueba de nuevo, he cambiado el nombre porque `switch` es una palabra reservada

Comment: no hace nada, en la consola no se muestra ningún valor ni nada

Comment: ¿donde y como estas ejecutando dicho código? y ¿qué error es exactamente el que te aparece?

Comment: ejecuto mi html en el que tengo referido el javascript, y no me da ningun error simplemente le doy al checkbox y no sale nada en la consola

Comment: El código de @DavidFernándezFlores funciona. Si en tu proyecto no funciona es porque te falta agregar algo. Asegúrate de agregar el evento `onchange="switchChange()"` en el `input` y que si es un archivo `JS` aparte, esté vinculado de manera correcta en el `HTML`.